# Polling for Square Device status

Tags: square-connect

What's the possibility to know whether the contactless device is turned on via the Square API? Is there a polling mode that the device will respond if it is in idle and waiting for a transaction?

If the device gone to sleep mode, what's the possibility to turn it on pragmatically?

Also will the device turn on automatically when it is connected via the USB cable to a USB port?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, programmatically checking the status of a reader and turning it on  isn’t currently available. The reader will automatically go into sleep mode after 2 hours of inactivity. To wake it up from sleep mode, firmly press the button on the side of the reader.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

What would be the possibility of keeping the device active? Can we simply poll the device periodically? 

Also does it automatically turn on after connecting to the USB cable?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Unfortunately there isn't a way to periodically poll the device, but if its continuously plugged in it will automatically reconnect even after long periods of inactivity.

Comment: Appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Appreciate your feedback. Just to clarify further, if the device is plugged into USB and even it goes to sleep mode after 2h of inactivity, it will auto reconnect with a new transactionction request via Bluetooth/SDK?      So my understanding is the device is going into deep sleep mode to save power but it is interruptable?    Also does device is ready to connect after first time plugged in?    Do we need to push the button there at least once?